# Flask WTForms - Dynamic BooleanField from database

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

In my flask project I have  views.py, models.py (SQLAlchemy to postgres), and forms.py files.  I have been defining forms in form.py an instantiating them from views.py.

I was able to create dynamic content for a SelectField, but having difficulty doing this for BooleanField.  Here is what I am trying to do:

Create a form that retrieves players from a team (in db).  For each player a BooleanField is created.  If the 'active' field in the db is 1, the value is is checked(true), otherwise it is unchecked(false).  Users of the system can check/uncheck any box and then submit the form.

I have no problem iterating over the players but I can't seem to figure out how to generate unique names for each BooleanField (if they have the same name I will only get one value back).  I also need to dynamically pass the default value based on the active status of the user.

I did some research and saw a couple of ideas around matching one of my ORM models - but I'm not really trying to create a field entry to match every column in my ORM model for my players - just trying to pull some data and create a form on the fly.

Might be able to do this all within jinja2 templates but that doesn't seem to be the best approach...

OK - trying to get more basic now, still having a problem - BooleanField always returns False:

forms.py:

```
class myform(Form):
    available = BooleanField('available')
    submit = SubmitField('Save')
```

views.py:

```
form = myform(available=True)
```

webpage.html

```
Available: {{ form.available }}
```

When the webpage renders the Checkbox is checked (due to the available=True) which I am passing, but when I submit, value comes back as False).

What I did notice as strange is that even when the box is checked the rendered HTML - `<input id="available" type="checkbox" value="y" name="available" checked="">`

Checked="" doesn't make sense to me.  I noticed that when I remove 'available=True' then there is no checked="".  I would think proper HTML should be checked=checked..

Comment: Got the basics working -- working too late, I simply didn't have the BooleanField under my form heading in the html.  Still trying to do this dynamically..

Comment: if form.available becomes False thats mean something change it in the view and pass to the response, better if you print all view.py code